# hello , i have applied condition based ([required]= "falert.sample") field. and i have once submit the form validate only required field true

Tags: c#, angular

```
<input type="text" 
       placeholder="name"
       name="name"
       [(ngModel)]="myName"
       #name="ngModel" [required]="fAlert.sample1">

<input type="text" 
       placeholder="email"
       name="email"
       [(ngModel)]="myEmail"
       #email="ngModel" [required]="fAlert.sample2">

<button class="classBtn" type="submit"
        [disabled]="name.errors?.required || email.errors?.required">
    SEND
</button>
```

hello , i have applied condition based ([required]= "falert.sample") field.  and i have once submit the form validate only required field true

Comment: Seems to work OK. What is the issue?

Comment: [disabled]="fAlert.FlagExpire2.errors?.required||fAlert.flagNote.errors?.required"
this is index based is that working on so, i want to achive required fiels are condition based mandatory field

Comment: Well that is not visible in your question. Can you add the source code including the part that is not working? And add logging? Or make it available via stackblitz?

Comment: <div *ngFor="let fAlert of activeAlertPermissionLst;let i=index;">

<button mat-stroked-button color="primary" class="custom-strokedBtn"
                                  name="saveflags" [disabled]="fAlert.FlagExpire2.errors?.required||fAlert.flagNote.errors?.required" 
                                  (click)="isPersonSealed ? false :saveFlagAlert(fAlert,'tempFlagExpire_'+i);">
                                Save
                            </button>